# Simple bash script not working

Tags: bash, scripts, proxy

I'm pretty new to bash scripting. I'm trying to make a script to export the http_proxy variables. This is what I do from the terminal:

```
$export http_proxy=http://proxy21.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
$export https_proxy=https://proxy21.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
```

This works just fine. Now, here's my script (called setproxy):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ $1 -eq 22 ]
then
    export http_proxy=http://proxy22.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
    export https_proxy=https://proxy22.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
elif [ $1 -eq 21 ]
then
    export http_proxy=http://proxy21.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
    export https_proxy=https://proxy21.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
elif [ $1 -eq 61 ]
then
    export http_proxy=http://proxy61.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
    export https_proxy=https://proxy61.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
elif [ $1 -eq 62 ]
then
    export http_proxy=http://proxy62.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
    export https_proxy=https://proxy62.iitd.ernet.in:3128/
fi
```

Essentially, I want to set the appropriate proxy server depending on the input.
I put it in the bin folder, made it executable, added bin to the path, logged in and out.
The terminal accepts setproxy as a valid command (at leat there's no command not found error) But, when I do:

```
$setproxy 22
```

There is no effect. The proxy remains unchanged.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the script, a new child shell is invoked to run it. Its proxies are set, but the proxy of the parent process (your shell) can't be changed from a child process. Try *sourcing* the script, i.e. call it like

```
. setproxy 21
```

Then the script will be interpreted by your current shell.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Is there any way to avoid the . at the start?

Comment: The `.` is what makes it work.

Comment: Oh, ok. One more thing, how can I set the system wide proxy (ie, the one when I do Network -> Network Proxy -> (Set the proxy) -> Apply System wide)